# How to use objects.filter(user=request.user) in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I used `PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()` and want to show the result in templates. But, I get this error message:

```
FieldError at /auth/purchaseHistory/


Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: id, product_name, product_price, purchase_addr, purchase_date, purchase_id, purchase_id_id, purchase_name, purchase_phone
```

**purchaseinfo/models.py**

```
class PurchaseInfo(models.Model):
    purchase_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    purchase_addr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    purchase_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    ...and so on
```

**customlogin/views.py**

```
from purchaseinfo.models import PurchaseInfo
def purchaseHistory(request):
    history = PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
    return render(request,'customlogin/purchaseHistory.html',{'history':history})
```

**purchaseHistory.html**

```
{% for i in history %}
<tr>
    <td>{{i.purchase_id}}</td>
    <td>{{i.purchase_name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.purchase_addr}}</td>
    <td>{{i.purchase_phone}}</td>
    <td>{{i.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{i.product_price}}</td>
    <td>{{i.purchase_date}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it's look like there is no user field in your model, Please write you complete model code

Comment: you can remove values() function . it is not necessary in here. also, naming foreign key fields like product_id is not a good practice. You can just name it user. Furthermore since the name of your model is productInfo, you don't have to start all field names with pruchase.

Comment: I do not have much experience to make models. so i have many mistakes. Thank u for comment! - to :  aman kumar,  razieh babaee 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update your views to this:

```
history = PurchaseInfo.objects.filter(purchase_id=request.user).values()
```

In your model the foreign key relation to User model is `purchase_id` but in views you are trying to filter by `user`. You need to filter by `purchase_id`.
Most of time the error messages explain the problem pretty well, try to understand what it's saying and attempt to fix it on your own. Debugging is a nice skill to have.